# Writing null safe package for flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

As of today, null safety isn't available on the stable channel for flutter.

However I would like to write a package that is null safe.

If I want people that don't opt-in null safety to use said package, do I need to maintain 2 versions of that package ? One with null safety and one without ? If so are there tools for automatically transpose from null safe code to old non null safe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now you're encouraged to submit it to pub with a pubspec requiring `2.12.0-259.9.beta` as a minimum.  The pub solver will note that it's out of reach for any non-null-safe dart, and ignore it. (`pub outdated` still reports it though.)  More details at https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide#version.

And yes, you'll have to publish two different versions (hopefully under different major numbers) until flutter stable includes 2.12 (actually, it might already... no, it's dart stable 2.10).

Comment: That link is more about migration than new packages.. It provide a `dart migrate` command, but if you write a *new* package there is no command to migrate from null safety to non null safety. So I guess I have to do the opposite, which is quite a bummer..